# Is it possible to add motion blur to an OBS Studio stream?

Tags: obs-studio

Is it possible to add motion blur to a livestream on OBS Studio, to make it look smoother, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoGx5GRbSfM&t=2s) video for an example but can I do it on a livestream?

Answer (score 0):

First, Go to Settings > Video and choose 24 - 30 - 60 fps and Bilinear in Downscale Filter.

[image: screenshot]

2. Create 3 "Screen Recorder"

[image: screenshot]

3. In the second "Screen Recorder", go to Filters > add > Color correction and change the opacity to 50

[image: screenshot]

4. Do the same thing in the third "Screen Recorder" But with an Opacity of 25
5. Et Voila ! you have now Motion Blur

This should work on low end PCs and high end PCs Running GNU/Linux distribution (I use Lubuntu).

Comment: I think you forgot the "Render delay filter". Anyway, even with that, it didn't work well for me. I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, i found a new method where you can use more than 2 or 3 Game Capture screens by putting a second Game Capture duplicated by `Duplicate (Reference)` inside a Group Folder and editing the group folder's filters with Color Correction then adding 30 - 70 ms of Render delay (render delay may depend on how high your fps is. mine is currently on 40 ms on 50 PAL) then there you go.

It should look something like this:

[image: example]

This method is better since using too many Window Captures (for me) lags my OBS.